# Chaining Core Animation animations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

Which is the most elegant and modular way to chain animation in a **Core Animation** context?

I mean to do animations that starts just when other finished (for example, changing `position` and then `opacity`).. normal approach is to directly change properties:

```
layer.position = new_point;
layer.opacity = 0.0f;
```

but this will do them at the same time. I want to make one wait for the other.

And what about chaining animations for different objects? I've read about `CATransaction` used like:

```
[CATransaction begin]
layer1.property = new_property;
[CATransaction begin]
layer2.property2 = new_property2;
[CATransaction commit];
[CATransaction commit];
```

but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can also use animation grouping and use the beginTime field of the animation. Try something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *posAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[posAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[posAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
// Here's the important part
[posAnimation setDuration:10.0];
[posAnimation setBeginTime:0.0];

CABasicAnimation *borderWidthAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderWidth"];
[borderWidthAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[borderWidthAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
// Here's the important part
[borderWidthAnimation setDuration:10.0];
[borderWidthAnimation setBeginTime:5.0];

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[group setDuration:10.0];
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:posAnimation, borderWidthAnimation, nil]];

[layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

Notice that the duration of the entire animation is 10 seconds. The first one starts at second 0 and the second one starts at 5 seconds.

Comment: note that this is great, but will only work for animations applied to a single layer.

Comment: Also if you want to call a method as soon as the first animation is finished, you can't. animationDidStop gets called only when the whole group is finished.

Comment: key path `"position"` is a `CGPoint` which needs to be encoded with `NSValue` (not a `NSNumber`).

Comment: Putting the animations inside a group is not triggering the animationDidStop delegate. Overall it's the simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

As Matt pointed out, you can create animation groups that consist of different animations for the same layer with different begin times. You can also set a delegate for stand-alone `CAAnimation` objects or `CAAnimation` Groups and as each animation finishes it will call an `animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method (note that animations that are part of a group won't call their delegate's `animationDidStop:finished:` method.

I figured out a cool trick that makes using the `CAAnimation animationDidStop:finished:` method more powerful. I use the method `setValue:forKey:` to add a block of code to a stand-alone animation or animation group, with the key @"animationCompletionBlock". I then write a general `animationDidStop:finished:` method that checks the just-completed animation for a @"animationCompletionBlock" key, and if it finds it, execute the block of code there.

Take a look at this project on github for a working example of that technique:

[CAAnimation demo with completion blocks](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)

You an also Set a group of animations inside a

```
[CATransaction begin];
//...
[[CATransaction commit];
```

block, as you suggested. When you do that, you can using the `CATransaction` class method `setCompletionBlock:` to invoke a block of code when all the animations in the current transaction group complete. The completion block for one transaction can then trigger the next transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I pull this off using the `setCompletionBlock` method to define a closure that triggers the next animation when the first one is finished:

```
[CATransaction begin]
layer1.property = new_property;
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    [CATransaction begin]
    layer2.property2 = new_property2;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can "nest" CA animations as you have in your example.

You need to specify a **delegate** for the animation and put your second "transition" within the `animationDidStop:finished:` selector of the delegate.

Might want to have a look at Apple's [Animation Types & Timing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

What I have always preferred to setting the begin and end time of each animation seperately is this:

I used A2DynamicDelegate (whose development is now happening in the [BlocksKit](https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit)-Repo, who knows why <_<) to implement a completionBlock property in a Category on CAAnimation.

This enabled me to do stuff like this:

```
CAAnimation *a = ...
CAAnimation *b = ...
CAAnimation *c = ...

a.completionHandler = ^{
    [self.layer addAnimation:b forKey:@"foo"];
    [self.layer addAnimation:c forKey:@"bar"];
};
```

Much more flexible :)

I've uploaded my code for completion handler [here](https://gist.github.com/Ahti/4982757). Have a look at the notice in the header file though. I am really confused why the method isn't called.

Answer (score -1):

Without including all the "tricks" up my "toolchain", this example  isn't directly copy/pastable… but it does show a REALLY easy strategy for "chained" animations..

```
CATransform3D trans = m34();  // define chain-wide constants.
// Name your "stack". My "nextObject" returns arr[i]->done == nil. 
NSArray *layerStack = layer.sublayers;
//define a block, that "takes" a layer as it's argument.
void(^__block ChainBlock)(CALayer*) = ^(CALayer *m) { 
// animations, transforms, etc for each inividual "step".
    [m animate:@"transform" 
          // These are just NSValue-wrapped CAT3D's
          from:AZV3d(CATransform3DRotate(trans,  0,1,0,0)) 
            to:AZV3d(CATransform3DRotate(trans,1.5,1,0,0)) 
          time:2    // total time == each step * layerStack.count
         eased:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut
    completion:^{   // In completion, look for "next" layer.
                    CAL*  m2 = [layers nextObject]; 
// If there is "another" layer, call this block, again... with it.
                      if (m2)  chainAnis(m2);
// Otherise,you're done.  Cleanup, toggle values, whatevs.
                     else self.finishedProperty = YES;
    }];
};
// Give the block we just defined your "first" layer.
ChainBlock(layerStack[0]);  // It will recursively feed itself.
```

This obviously depends on some "external magic", but the concept is simple, and eliminates (through dependencies) the need to "deal with" ANY sort of *gross delegation.*  In particular, the `animate:from:to:time:easing:completion`, etc. categories come from the great [FunSize Framework, on Github](https://github.com/mralexgray/FunSize).