# How slow down or accelerate animation using curves in Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios4, caanimation

I am using CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint to create a curve path for animation and have animation duration for example 2 second. How can I animate object what moving along this path for example from one point to another is slower then in other points and within this 2 seconds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Chaining Core Animation animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908480/chaining-core-animation-animations) on SO, it describes a solution to chain animations. You can set the duration and curves for each animation seperately then.