# NSAnimation looping

Tags: cocoa, animation, loops

I've a view that starts an animation when the user drag files on it. The animation shows the files' relative icon (inside an NSImageView Ivar of the NSAnimation custom class) going bigger while fading.

If I loop the animation inside a standard loop like:

```
CustomAnimation *animation = [[CustomAnimation alloc] initWithDuration: 2.0 animationCurve: NSAnimationLinear]

NSimage *icon;

for (NSString *filename in filenames) {
    icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile: filename];
    NSImageView *myImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: theFrame];
    [myImageView setImage: icon];
    [animation setImageView: myImageView];
    [animation startAnimation];
}
```

The loop is too fast and the animations looks like if it were fired almost together (obviously).

What do you think is the best approach to loop an animation several times controlling the delay between the start of one animation and the subsequent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your animation blaze by (except perhaps the last one) is that at each iteration  your are "overwriting" the previous animation with a new one.

This post on [chaining core animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908480/chaining-core-animation-animations) together should do the trick if the idea is to have each animation take the full 2s. You can event add gaps between the animations.

-- Edit --

@Richard that's my mistake, I've misread the question.

A look at the documentaton for NSAnimation suggests that you might use `startWhenAnimation:reachesProgress:` to chain your animations though.

Comment: OP is using `NSAnimation`, not Core Animation.

Comment: Yeah, I've already considered that option, the fact is that I was looking for an elegant way to achieve this result. Using startWhenAnimation:reachesProgress: I have to face the fact that soon my app could alloc a gazillion NSAnimation object if the user drags for example 80 applications on the receiver view :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTimer` for that purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried with NSTimer but then a strange behavior rise. After the timer has fired the method, the application hangs up and crash. Probably I'm doing the wrong thing. I passed the NSAnimation object as the userInfo, then i start the animation in the selector method retrieving the object from NSTimer.