# Animation Direction on iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

I know everything about animation Tools in iOS.
Rotation, Scaling and Moving but I have made a bad timing

for example I have two Squares one on the Left and the Other on the Right 
and i want the two squares two rotates until they hit each other with Angle
but i fail to make it because of bad timing

so my Question is their a god tutorial illustrate it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908480/chaining-core-animation-animations) link. As Your Tags suggest that you´re using CoreAnimation for that, you can chain your animations.

You could have a fixed moving horizontal and a nested animation with the same duration for rotating. Thats how i do such tasks.

**UPDATE:**
Here is some code which works perfectly for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 70.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:leftView];

    UIView *rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:rightView];

    [self moveViewLeft:leftView];
    [self moveViewRight:rightView];

}

- (void)moveViewLeft:(UIView *)view {

    float duration = 1.0;

    // Moving
    CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x, [view center].y)];
    moveAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x+self.view.frame.size.width/2-view.frame.size.width, [view center].y)];
    moveAnimation.duration = duration;
    moveAnimation.speed = 1.0;
    moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Rotation
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((360*M_PI)/180)];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration+0.5;
    rotationAnimation.speed = 1.5;
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Combining Animations

    CAAnimationGroup *anim = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    anim.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnimation, rotationAnimation, nil];
    anim.duration = duration;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];

}

- (void)moveViewRight:(UIView *)view {

    float duration = 1.0;

    // Moving
    CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x, [view center].y)];
    moveAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([view center].x-self.view.frame.size.width/2, [view center].y)];
    moveAnimation.duration = duration;
    moveAnimation.speed = 1.0;
    moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Rotation
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((360*M_PI)/180)];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration+5;
    rotationAnimation.speed = 1.5;
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Combining Animations

    CAAnimationGroup *anim = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    anim.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnimation, rotationAnimation, nil];
    anim.duration = duration;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];

}
```

**Update 2:**
I've changed the duration of the rotation and the speed. Now it looks like your example animation. Both squares are fitting now to each other.

**Update 3:**
As you say, that you have timing problems, following guide helped me for this:

- The duration of the rotation should be equal to the speed.
- The duration and the speed should be 150% of the duration and speed of the moving animation.

Comment: i know how to make timing but my problem is choosing the perfect time

Comment: I´ve added some code that works for me

Comment: Thanks Man for the tutorial but i do not want some code i want Learn how to make a good timing

Comment: Learning timing is a bit hard. It involves some math and maybe physics. For your example i have added another update with a guide how it works. Maybe it helps you to find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing UICollisionBehavior? If so, try to disable it.