# Animating UIImageViews for 1 second each in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, nsarray

I'm trying to do some `animation` with `UIImageView`'s...

I have an `NSArray` containing 3 `UIImageView`'s which have been connected and declared in the .h using the interface builder.

I also have a sequencer which has been set to call these images from the `NSArray` when appropriate.

As it stands, the sequencer calls the first image in the `NSArray`, displaying the image on the screen as desired.

However, when more than one image is called the images are displayed at the same time on screen, rather than one after the other.

Is there any way of assigning an individual time of 1 second to these separate images so that when they are called, the second, third, image does not display until the previous image have finished being shown for 1 second?

I hope this makes sense, any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your code. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. When you say "animating", do you just mean showing a sequence of images (with no fancy transitions)? If so, you can use the [`animationImages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages) property of `UIImageView`.

Comment: Checkout: [Chaining Core Animation animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908480/chaining-core-animation-animations)

Comment: the array is, `self.pianoLoadImages =  @[self.pianoLoadImage1, self.pianoLoadImage2, self.pianoLoadImage3];`

Comment: I literally just need a way to give `pianoLoadImage1`, `pianoLoadImage2`, `pianoLoadImage3` individually assigned durations of 1 second. So that they appear (no fancy transitions) and the next image won't show until the previous has lasted 1 second

Comment: @hbondy So what's wrong with just using `animationImages`? That's what it's designed for (showing a sequence of images). You can change `animationDuration` to suit your needs then.

Comment: will `animationImages` work then even though the images are not always displayed in order? My sequence works as follows: First image is displayed: user clicks on image. First and Second images displayed (for 1 second each, one after the other): user clicks on first and second image. etc etc

Answer (score 0):

#### You'll want to use the [`animationImages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages) property of `UIImageView`

This will allow you to play a sequence of images to the user. You'll just want to pass in an array of the images that you want to cycle through. From what it sounds like, you'll need to pass in a new array after user input. You can use `NSArray`'s [`subarrayWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:) method to pass in a given range of elements from your array of images.

You'll also want to set the [`animationDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationDuration) property to `1.0*imageCount` – where `imageCount` is the number of images to cycle through, and `1.0` is the time for *each* image to be displayed on-screen for (as [`animationDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationDuration) takes the *total* duration).

From what it sounds like, you don't want the sequence to repeat once it's finished – so you'll also want to set [`animationRepeatCount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationRepeatCount) to 1.

You can then invoke the sequence of images by calling [`-startAnimating`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/startAnimating) on your image view.

Comment: Thank you @originaluser2, I will have a go and see if I get the results I'm hoping for! Then will be able to confirm your answer!

Comment: Just to confirm, my sequencer performs just like the 'Simon Memory Game'. So I have already set up sounds, just trying to add images to show alongside the notes!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.2 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    -(void)changeImage
     {
      imageVw.alpha = 1.0f;
      [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{imageVw.alpha=0.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){

        if (counter>=_imgArr.count)
        {
            counter =0;
        }
        imageVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imgArr objectAtIndex:counter]];
        [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{imageVw.alpha=1.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }];

    counter++;
```

}